# Is there a way to flush the contents of a view at some point without using if-else statements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface

Is there a way to flush the contents of a view at some point without using if-else statements?
For example, If I'm listing a bunch of records using a table, but I don't need the headers if no rows are found: maybe a message saying, "No data found". I'd like to:

```
if (records.count == 0) {
  <div>No Data</div>
  return; //flush/render view
}
//no else
<table><tr><th>......</tr>
foreach (var record in records) {
  <tr><td>....</tr>
}
</table>
```

Makes sense? Or I'm just being lazy: I hate huge chunks of nested code, especially inside a view where indentation is not so sleak.

Comment: In cases like this I usually use a second view of type `Record`. It makes the code simpler to read, and a good percentage of the time I'll be reusing that `Record` view somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, it should work:

```
@if (records.count == 0)
{
    <div>No Data</div>
    return;
}

<table>
    <tr><th>......</tr>
    foreach (var record in records) 
    {
        <tr><td>....</tr>
    }
</table>
```

If the condition (`records.count == 0`) is satisfied only `No Data` will be printed on the Razor view and the subsequent code will never be executed and the table will never be shown.

Comment: Are you sure that *return* will work? In ASPX it would not. Does it in razor? Is it documented?

Comment: It works! What?? Wow! Thanks @Darin. I tested it with an aspx/ascx view.